# Need to transform Razor code on ASPX code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So, I need help to make this code work as ASPX, can anyone help me?

I know it,s just a few parts to be changed, but i don't know how to do it...

Or if Any one know hot to achive the same result other way this would be very helpfull.

I already try do it myself but got no luck doing so.. =/

So, I need help to make this code work as ASPX, can anyone help me?

I know it,s just a few parts to be changed, but i don't know how to do it...

Or if Any one know hot to achive the same result other way this would be very helpfull.

I already try do it myself but got no luck doing so.. =/

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Employee List";
    }

    <a class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom:10px" 
    onclick="PopupForm('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","Employee")')"><i class="fa fa-
    plus"></i> Add New</a>
    <table id="employeeTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" 
    style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    @section scripts{
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var Popup, dataTable;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            dataTable =  $("#employeeTable").DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Employee/GetData",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Name" },
                    { "data": "Position" },
                    { "data": "Office" },
                    { "data": "Age" },
                    { "data": "Salary" },
                    {"data":"EmployeeID" , "render" : function (data) {
                        return "<a class='btn btn-default btn-sm' onclick=PopupForm('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","Employee")/" + data + "')><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Edit</a><a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' style='margin-left:5px' onclick=Delete("+data+")><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete</a>";
                    },
                        "orderable": false,
                        "searchable":false,
                        "width":"150px"
                    }

                ],
                "language": {

                    "emptyTable" : "No data found, Please click on <b>Add New</b> Button"
                }
            });
        });

        function PopupForm(url) {
            var formDiv = $('<div/>');
            $.get(url)
            .done(function (response) {
                formDiv.html(response);

                Popup = formDiv.dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    title: 'Fill Employee Details',
                    height: 500,
                    width: 700,
                    close: function () {
                        Popup.dialog('destroy').remove();
                    }

                });
            });
        }

        function SubmitForm(form) {
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
            if($(form).valid()){
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : form.action,
                    data : $(form).serialize(),
                    success : function (data) {
                        if(data.success)
                        {
                            Popup.dialog('close');
                            dataTable.ajax.reload();

                            $.notify(data.message,{
                                globalPosition :"top center",
                                className : "success"
                            })

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        }

        function Delete(id) {
            if(confirm('Are You Sure to Delete this Employee Record ?'))
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("Delete","Employee")/' + id,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success)
                        {
                            dataTable.ajax.reload();

                            $.notify(data.message, {
                                globalPosition: "top center",
                                className: "success"
                            })

                        }
                    }

                });
            }
        }
    </script>
}
```

Comment: What did you try? What happened?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is not working? and exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: If you already tried, where's your attempt? What goes wrong with it? Maybe it's not very far from being right. Show us.